# React - re-render components when linking between parameterized routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I recently reconfigured my React app, and it seems that I have broken the functionality of my parameterized routes.  Rather than going too deep into how it used to work, I'll describe what I am currently stuck with and what I am aiming to achieve...

In a navigation panel on the side of my page, a user can view a list of links to resources - the urls for these links would be something like:

```
user/123
user/456
user/789
group/123
group/456
group/789
```

Clicking the first link will now render the `User` component in the main `div` on my page (rendering in `{this.props.children}` - see `App.jsx` below), and a call to `componentDidMount()` pulls data for the user with id `123` and populates the component.  Ok, so far, so good.

However, if a user now clicks on the link for `user/456`, nothing happens.  The url in the navbar changes, but the `User` component does not re-render, though clicking a link for a `group` will correctly clear out the `User` component and render the `Group` component instead...  then, of course, I have the same problem with the groups, etc...

How can I force the re-rendering of a component when the pathname remains the same but the parameter has changed? If I've clicked the link for `user/123` and then I click the link for `user/456`, I want that `User` component to re-render and pull the new data.

Other relevant code...

`index.js`

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="/user/:id" component={User} />
        <Route path="/group/:id" component={Group} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

`App.jsx`

```
<div className="App">
    <div className="body_section_container">
        <div className="body_section main">
            <Nav />
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
        <div className="body_section sidebar">
        <Search searchModel={this.searchAll} user_list={this.state.user_list} group_list={this.state.group_list} organizations_list={this.state.organizations_list} />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try plugging into `componentWillReceiveProps`, which should fire when the route params change.

Comment: What's the react-router version you are using?

Comment: @NickSalloum Oh yes, thank you!  I have to work with it a little bit, but I can see that `componentWillReceiveProps` is triggered when the route params changed. If you would parse that as an answer, I'd surely accept it.

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara I'm using version 3.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try plugging into `componentWillReceiveProps`, which should fire when the route params change. Then you can receive the new route params, submit a new query, and update state.

Comment: Great, thank you!  I was able to resolve my problem by wrapping a call to `this.componentDidMount()` inside `componentWillReceiveProps()`.

Answer (score 0):

In the Route component, specify a key.

```
<Route path={YOURPATH} render={(props) => <YourComp {...props} keyProp={id} key={id}/>} />
```

when react see a different key, it will trigger rerender.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting, thank you. I'll try this out.